# How to set value for annotation - Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, annotations

Let me explain my problem: I'm trying to test with Mockito in JUnit4, a method of Class1, which calls a static void method in Util1, this method of Util1 calls another method of Class2, just to check if conditions are correct. If not, the method in Util1 enter in exception. In this method of Class2, has a @Value annotation instantiated which value are returning null, and thats my problem, i need the spring get @Value provider in application.properties(on test or main, wherever) or i can set a value for this variable. I've tried several ways to pass this value to the class(or variable), but so far I can't change the value of this variable. How do I resolve this issue?

What I already tried:

1. Use ReflectionTestUtils.setField to set the variable in the class, mocking and not mocking the class in the test.
2. Use the @SpringBootTest and @TestPropertySource annotations to get the test's application.properties
3. PowerMocking

But none of these alternatives worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito can't directly mock static methods, so you can use PowerMock along with Mockito. PowerMock is a library that extends Mockito and allows you to mock static methods.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Util1.class, Class2.class})
public class Class1Test {

    @Test
    public void testClass1Method() {
        // Mock the static method in Util1
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util1.class);
        Mockito.when(Util1.staticMethod()).thenReturn(someValue);

        // Mock the @Value dependency in Class2
        // Assuming you are using Spring and have the appropriate setup
        @TestPropertySource(properties = {"your.value.property=your_mocked_value"})
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = Class2.class)
        public static class Class2Test {
        }

        // Now, test the method in Class1 that you want to test
        // Make sure to pass any necessary dependencies or use Mockito.verify() to check interactions.
    }
}
```

Comment: The method in Util1 is void, it is just check if method in Class2 is correctly, if not get in exception. But the method in Class2 uses a @Value provider annotation to check if it is correct, how i mencioned. And that is my problem, because this value are returning null, not get the provider on application.properties(on test or main, wherever). In the other words, when you reach to the line of the method in Class1, where's called the void method in Util1, it will just check if the method in Class2 is correct. I will update my  question